# No disk file outside grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, initramfs

I have issue with my disks I can't boot from them
I can't get them to display outside grub program.

When I try to boot from them I'm dropped to initramfs after ~30 seconds of boot time.

From initramfs I don't see any block device in /dev, same situation with live instance of Ubuntu but in case of grub I'm able to access all partitions And files.

I see all filesystem uuids,  types of partitions

Both disks are connected via m2 interface.

This problem occured in time when device was in usual use, I have plugged USB DAC to usb-c port, system reaction was immediate black screen, unresponsive to any input.
Any ideas?

Gnu grub 2.06

Ubuntu 22 LTS

Comment: Sounds like a possible failed initramfs creation on kernel update. Have you tried to boot with previous kernel version(s) in the "Advanced options for..." submenu in GRUB? For SATA disks, you should typically have modules `sd_mod`, `scsi_mod`, `libata`, `libahci` and `ahci` included in your initramfs and automatically loaded. For NVMe disks, the necessary modules are `nvme`, `nvme_core`, and `t10_pi`. In initramfs prompt, run `lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules` to see what modules have been successfully loaded. Also check `dmesg` output for errors.

Comment: Well, i had run from oldest kernel available, loaded all nesesery modules for nvme you mentioned but unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: Just to be sure, I have to do only modprobe, nothing else?

Comment: Are you aware that the Linux block devices for NVMe devices look like `/dev/nvme0n1` and partitions like `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, not like `/dev/sd*` at all? Yes, `modprobe` should work just fine to load the modules.

Comment: Yes, they are not showing in /dev. In my case system was installed on nvme1p1,2

Comment: That is really strange. Sounds like a firmware bug of some sort... is your BIOS up to date? Or if the system worked before, and plugging in the USB DAC caused the system to crash, that seems like a possible short circuit that may have fried some components... no fun at all.

Comment: I know it's strange, I'm struggling with this for 4 hours, bios it's up to date. Btw. Running from grub command line also has no effect, after boot I'm still drop to initramfs

Comment: Well In case of this DAC I used have it for 3 months now, it crashed when I plugged it to my second USB c (thunderbolt) port both ports worked  perfectly until now, we'll now (at least) USB capabilities work's I have plugged my yubikey and it's showing in devices

Comment: I also thought that I had fried something but after a little struggling with windows installation ( I had to recreate MBR) windows had boot correctly. After that I trayed Linux again when this didn't worked I booted windows from grub (not from it's own boot manager) and it seems to broke it. But I don't care about windows it's not my default os :/

Comment: I also looked through log, there was some acpi bug's but if I remember correctly those ones always where there, I don't have access to 'more', so I had read logs though dd, awfull experience 

Comment: After few dozen minutes in bios I was able to show my disk in live instance ( problem with installed one was still intact) from this point I was able to check file system, repaired it and..... this worked, anyway thanks for your time, btw how it is possible that broken file system results in disk  don't even show up in devices list?

Comment: A broken file system should not cause that. But you might check if the SSD manufacturer has a firmware update available for it: some sort of firmware hang or other issue in the SSD could cause both the broken filesystem *and* the device showing intermittently (works OK for BIOS & GRUB, then goes off to sulk as Linux probes for it, then eventually comes back).

Answer (score 0):

Repairing filesystem from live-os had resolved problem.